# WINE and RAM issues

Tags: 20.04, wine, ram, playonlinux

I was wondering if there is a way to increase the RAM in WINE.  Lag is terrible while trying to play games via WINE

Comment: You may also want to correct the spelling mistake in the title of the question so others will find it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open PlayOnLinux
2. Click on Tools -> PlayOnLinux console
3. execute `POL_Config_Write VMS 2048` You may give a different value than 2048. Remember to give the size in MB. Hope this helps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would help with the lagging issues?  I really am tired of the lag I'm having.

Comment: Hey that actually made my system entire system to shut down.

Comment: It's sad to hear that the system was shutdown. It would generally not. The shut down might be caused by lack of available memory space. You may check if the configuration was written successfully by issuing the command `POL_Config_Read VMS`. It should show the value you provided. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes it shows 2048

Comment: Ok. Now is it running or crashing? or slow as before?

Comment: It is slower than before and will freeze then crash